# Exclude all sticky posts front page twenty twelve

Tags: query, frontpage, exclude, sticky-post

I am attempting to exclude all sticky posts from my front page in twenty twelve theme. I have attempted the following. I am making all changes to the child theme.

1. To remove the following code from content.php

   ```
   <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
   <div class="featured-post">
       <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
2. Add following code to index.php before the loop(this removed sticky posts but broke pagination)

   ```
   <?php query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) ); ?>
   ```

This is the loop in index.php (pretty much standard index.php for twenty twelve.

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>



        <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

Could someone please advise me on what I should exactly put into this loop to not show any sticky posts on index.php?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Use a filter on [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

```
function no_front_sticky_wpse_98680($qry) {
  if (is_front_page()) {
    $qry->set('post__not_in',get_option( 'sticky_posts' ));
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','no_front_sticky_wpse_98680');
```

By running `query_posts` you clobber the main query, over-writing it with another query. That is why you break pagination. The new query gets out of sync with what should be the main query.

Comment: I assume you would add this above to functions.php, but would I need to add anything inside the loop of index.php such as <?php no_front_sticky_wpse_98680() ?>

Comment: Just add it to `functions.php`. Nothing else is required. That will modify the main query for the front page.

Comment: @UkrVolk11 : if this solved the problem please mark it as "Accepted"